# 3-wire dryer circuit and whole house generator

Tags: electrical

I got an estimate for a Generac whole house standby generator a while back, but didn't pull the trigger. I actually had 2 different estimates and one of the electricians had pointed out an issue with my dryer circuit that the other did not.

I might not remember the details exactly, but I think the issue was that they would need to remove the existing bond between neutral and ground in my main panel and instead bond them in the transfer switch. This is because neutral and ground should only be bonded in one place (i.e. not in both transfer switch and main panel). Also, does this bond need to be where the service enters the house so that it can also be connected to the service neutral wire?

The problem with the 3-wire dryer circuit is that neutral is used as a ground, which is effectively bonding them together at the appliance. This isn't as much of a problem without the extra panel because there is a continuous connection between earth and the dryer neutral-ground via the connection in the main panel. Anyway, the electrician who pointed this out said that either I'd have to convert the dryer to gas, or run a new 4-wire circuit (i.e. separate ground and neutral). The OTHER electrician never asked about the dryer and didn't mention the issue.

Did I get this right? If not, where am I missing something?

What are the reasons for these requirements and was the OTHER electrician wrong to miss this or is it more a case of "good enough" vs. "best".

Comment: That type of dryer circuit has been banned from being installed since 1996.  if older than that it is allowed to be left in place, but it is recommended to upgrade it to the safer four wire circuit.  The "other" electrician might have wrongly assume it was the modern four wire circuit.  If the house or that circuit is newer than 1996 , then that circuit must be changed since it was never in code/legal to put in.

Comment: The dryer does **not** create a bond - it just exposes neutral on the surfaces that should be grounded, if a 4-wire (NEMA14)  connection as has been required since the 1996 code cycle was used as opposed to the "still killing, mostly children" grandfathered (if installed before 1996 was adopted) or illegal (if later, or if done with a /2 with ground cable as opposed to a /3 no ground cable, at any time) NEMA 10. In many cases there's a perfectly good ground wire sitting unused behind the NEMA 10 plug. Have a look (with the breaker off, of course.)

Comment: Did the electrician who pointed out the dryer issue say that he would only do the generator if he did the dryer first?   Perhaps the hazy element in your memory is just that the two were tightly coupled, when in fact the electrician was just upselling you on a second job?  One that is in fact a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

The neutral-ground bond must be in the first box in the service after the meter, which would be the transfer switch if you put one in. It only involves separating the grounds and neutrals in the formerly-main circuit breaker panel to different un-connected bus bars inside the circuit breaker panel, and running a correctly-sized extra ground wire back to the transfer switch.

The 3-wire dryer connection is not actually a neutral-ground bond, if the circuit is not supplied through metal conduit. It is bootlegging ground for the dryer case from the neutral wire in the supply circuit, on the idea that neutral is supposed to be at the same voltage as ground. However, this theory has proven dangerously unstable in practice, and can leave the dryer case connected to the high voltage supply. It is far better to run a new 4-wire (two powers, neutral and ground) to the dryer, and replace the dryer cord with a 4-wire dryer cord. Replacing the dryer with a gas dryer is also an option, depends on what you want and if gas is easily accessible. (FWIW a gas dryer will not need nearly so much power from the generator as the electric dryer would, so a gas dryer is  quite a viable change from a generator standpoint.)

One thing to consider, sparked by a comment by "Tiger Guy" below, is if the dryer power is supplied through metal conduit. The conduit may provide ground, and the neutral-case bond may then be a ground-neutral bond that must be removed. With conduit as ground, that is really a 4 wire dryer circuit.

The reason for the only-one-point-of-connection between neutral and ground is to prevent power from running on the ground circuit in various failure conditions, which would render the grounds in the whole house energized and liable to electrocute someone. Having that point of connection in the first box into the house means the path for ground electricity is as low resistance as possible, and more likely to protect people. Also, not connecting neutral and ground except in the first box allows GFCIs to work better.

Comment: The 3 wire dryer connection is a problem, but does it have anything to do with changing the neutral-ground?  it isn't connecting the 2, it's only 3 wires, no ground wire, right?

Comment: @TigerGuy assuming something isn't being done unusually in Thomas Esposito's house, normal 3-wire dryer circuits are two powers and neutral, no ground. The case is connected to neutral. There is no connection to house ground, because no ground wire. However, if the dryer circuit is in metal conduit all the way back to the panel, the conduit may provide ground, and the neutral-case bond may then be a ground-neutral bond that must be removed. With conduit as ground, that is really a 4 wire dryer circuit.

Comment: This does not answer (what I believe to be) the question, which is why moving the bond from main panel to transfer switch makes the dryer problem any worse or triggers a requirement to change the dryer wiring immediately?

Comment: @jay613, If I read correctly, there's actually two questions: Does the house neutral ground bond need to move, and is the dryer another neutral ground bond. I think I've covered those.

Answer (score 4):

Basically it is a confusion of two *different* types of neutral-ground bond:

- Panel or transfer switch - connect the neutral *for the entire house* to the ground *for the entire house*. This must be done in one place, and as already explained, with a whole house generator this is done at the transfer switch rather than in the main panel.
- Old 3-wire Dryer - connect ground (metal case) of the dryer to the neutral wire of the house. This is supposed to be done (a) only if the circuit existed pre-1996 (and ideally only long before that) and (b) only if ground is not available. **This can cause a dangerous situation for the dryer, but has no effect on the rest of the house.**

So the electrician who said "must fix the dryer problem" is misunderstanding the meaning on neutral-ground bond with respect to a dryer (or range). In fact, if the neutral-ground bond is left in place on a dryer *and* the cord/plug/receptacle is changed to a 4-wire setup then this does present a real problem, but in that situation it is trivial to fix by removing the bond on the dryer.

That being said, it is best practices (i.e., safest) to switch dryers from 3-wire to 4-wire. There are 5 ways to do this:

- Replace with a gas dryer. As noted, that is great if you need to run the dryer during a blackout as it only needs power for motor and controls. But that is an expensive fix (new dryer, plumbing work)
- Run a new 4-wire cable from the panel to the dryer with a 4-wire receptacle. This can get expensive if the dryer is not near the panel.
- Install a GFCI double-breaker to power the dryer in place of a regular breaker, and then install a 4-wire receptacle *leaving the ground wire disconnected*. Label it "no ground" and you now have a safe solution as the GFCI will take care of nearly all serious problems.
- Retrofit ground - run *only* a ground wire from the panel (or certain other methods) to the dryer and replace the receptacle with a 4-wire receptacle.
- **Open up the 3-wire receptacle. Discover the ground wire sitting there waiting to be used. Replace the receptacle with a 4-wire receptacle.**

I like the last one. If your house is post-1996 it is extremely likely to be the case that there is a ground wire there. It is likely for any house from early 1970s and on.

Comment: Technically the label (which may even be provided in the package with the breaker) should read "GFCI Protected, No Equipment Ground" (or two labels, amounting to the same wording.)

Comment: The  GFCI method for 3 wires feeding 4 wire receptacle a is not accepted in some jurisdictions, reasoning the informational notes following 406.4(D)(3) are there to remind you that some appliances require a ground and are not approved for using an ungrounded receptacle.  That is why labelling the receptacle is required. Note 2 refers you to a  list of those appliances which 250.114(3)(b) specifically lists clothes-drying appliances.

Comment: I took some pictures of the plug and receptacle:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/cxGGZ6RVSZvKiLkB7

The house was built in 1979 and the dryer is probably 15-20 years old. My guess is that the dryer is 240V-only, because it doesn't have any digital controls, just mechanical buttons, dials, and a light inside. Otherwise, the bare ground wire in the picture of the receptacle would be carrying current which would be bad!

Comment: So I'm guessing there is no problem at all as-is, but I would have trouble if I wanted to replace the dryer with a model with digital controls which would probably require both 240V and 120V and a 4-prong plug. Do they even sell 240V-only dryers anymore, and if so, do they have 3-prong or 4-prong plugs? If 4-prong, do they just not use the neutral at all?

I can't check out my range easily because it is a slide-in unit that is flush with the island countertop, has rigid duct for downdraft, etc. The range does have digital controls.

Comment: Actually, since the dryer is newer than 1996, maybe it WAS already converted from 4-prong to 3-prong when it was installed and the bare wire IS carrying some current, although a small amount. I'd have to look how it is wired inside the breaker box to be sure.

Comment: Dryers don't come with cords. Why? Because cord length and type will vary, even without the 3 vs. 4 issue. So the appliance company delivers it, looks at what you've got and how long it needs to be (3 ft vs 4 ft vs 6 ft) and attaches whatever is needed. Almost all US dryers for the last 50+ years have used neutral. Why? To power the light bulb, controls and motor. Why? Because that way the manufacturer can make the exact same dryer for gas and electric - same case, drum, controls, motor, belt, light bulb, switches, etc. The only difference is: electric has a big heating element connected to

Comment: 240V and the gas has as igniter and related circuit connected to 120V + gas valve. There is no reason a dryer can't be designed to do everything with 240V - the catch is that the manufacturer would have to deal with more differences between the gas and electric models than they do right now. Since the standard (whether 3 without ground or 4 with ground) for an electric dryer has included neutral for decades, there is no reason to change it. From the appliance store perspective, they **can't** change your 3-wire to 4-wire receptacle for you (aside from that it would cost them money to do so)

Comment: in most jurisdictions either the homeowner can do it or you call an electrician. In a rental, you *must* call an electrician. So the 3-wire receptacles continue. I went through this myself - when I got my current dryer (sometime between 1999 and 2005 or so, can't remember exactly) I knew nothing about the grounding issue and the appliance company, as is normal, connected it to the existing 3-wire receptacle. When I got my panel replaced last year, I had my electrician put in a proper 4-wire receptacle and I changed the dryer cord (and remove the bond) to match.